# Set default scale in vis js network

Tags: javascript, canvas, vis.js-network, vis.js

I am using vis.js library to create a network topology. After I create the network using:

```
network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);
```

where container is the `canvas` on which I am drawing.

data :

```
{
    nodes: Nodes,
    edges: Edges
};
```

options :

```
{ 
    autoResize: true,
    nodes: {
        shape: 'image',
        size:  25,
        font: {
            size: 16,
            color: 'darkbrown'
        },
        borderWidth: 0,
        shadow: true
    },
    edges: {
        smooth: {
            forceDirection: "none"
        }
    },
    physics: {
        forceAtlas2Based: {
            springLength: 80,
            springConstant: 0.27
        },
        minVelocity: 0.75,
        solver: "forceAtlas2Based",
        timestep: 0.34
    },
    layout: {
        randomSeed: undefined
    },
    interaction: {
        hover: true
    }
}
```

After it is drawn the default scale(1) is very large with respect to my canvas. I want to resize the scale. I have tried this way :

```
network = new vis.Network(container, data, options); //network is drawn

var scaleOption = { scale : 0.5 }; -(1) 

network.moveTo(scaleOption); -(2)
```

It doesn't work this way. However, if (1) and (2) are fired inside a particular event say :

```
network.on("click",function(params) {

    var scaleOption = { scale : 0.5 };
    network.moveTo(scaleOption);
});
```

It works. I need to set the scale right at the beginning, i.e. right after topology is drawn(before the occurence of any such event). `AfterDrawing` event is continuously fired after the topology is drawn, so that fails too. Any way to resolve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `stabilized` event and `once` method to scale down your network for the first time it is drawn.

```
network.once('stabilized', function() {
    var scaleOption = { scale : 0.5 };
    network.moveTo(scaleOption);
})
```

Comment: network.once('startStabilizing', function() {
          var scaleOption = { scale : 0.8 };
          network.moveTo(scaleOption);
      });
This one worked best for me

Comment: Hi, may I ask, where is `startStabilizing` and `stabilized` refer to? id or class or name?

Comment: @mastersuse Your question is not clear to me. As far as I remember those are events, I am out of touch for quite some time. You can go through the docs: https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/docs/network/.

Comment: This method works, but making unpleasant jumps in scale.